# Select properties (inner SELECT) in LINQ with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I have a list of events which are unique based on their eventId and start/end times but otherwise they are the same. So for example, my dataItem looks like this...

```
eventItem.EventId
eventItem.EventTypeId
eventItem.StartDateTime 
eventItem.EndDateTime
eventItem.Available
eventItem.ShowSystemName
```

and my dataset looks like this...

> ```
> 408277 110 5/26/2021 3:00:00 PM 5/26/2021 3:45:00 PM 100 Event 1 
> 408551 109 5/26/2021 4:00:00 PM 5/26/2021 4:45:00 PM 100 Event 2 
> 408124 110 5/27/2021 10:30:00 AM 5/27/2021 11:15:00 AM 100 Event 1 
> 408398 109 5/27/2021 11:30:00 AM 5/27/2021 12:15:00 PM 100 Event 2 
> 408201 110 5/27/2021 1:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 1:45:00 PM 100 Event 1 
> 408475 109 5/27/2021 2:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 2:45:00 PM 100 Event 2 
> 408278 110 5/27/2021 3:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 3:45:00 PM 100 Event 1 
> 408552 109 5/27/2021 4:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 4:45:00 PM 100 Event 2
> ```

My desired query from that data would return each unique event only once (based on ShowSystemName) and then a list of subitems for that event. Something like..

```
Event 1
    408277 110 5/26/2021 3:00:00 PM 5/26/2021 3:45:00 PM
    408124 110 5/27/2021 10:30:00 AM 5/27/2021 11:15:00 AM 
    408201 110 5/27/2021 1:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 1:45:00 PM
    408278 110 5/27/2021 3:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 3:45:00 PM
 
Event 2
    408398 109 5/27/2021 11:30:00 AM 5/27/2021 12:15:00 PM
    408475 109 5/27/2021 2:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 2:45:00 PM 
    408552 109 5/27/2021 4:00:00 PM 5/27/2021 4:45:00 PM
    408551 109 5/26/2021 4:00:00 PM 5/26/2021 4:45:00 PM
```

I have started out with

```
foreach(var eventItem in result.Events.GroupBy(x => x.ShowSystemName).Select(x => x.First()))
{
    ...
}
```

which gets me each event only once as expected, but I am struggling with doing an inner select.

I am working in Razor because ultimately this will be rendered as HTML, but since the server call for the events is my code as well, I could move this logic into the service call if that buys me anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the inner select at all? `GroupBy()` will give you a list of events for each group with all you need as far I can tell.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride - You are absolutely right!! I was totally over thinking this (as usual) - would you mind creating an answer that changes my Select to (x=>x) and then looping through the System.Linq.Lookup<string, object>.Grouping instead? I'd like to give you credit for the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy()` will not return event items but *groups* of event items. Specifically it's an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`s where `TKey` is the type of what you grouped by (a `string`) and `TElement` is your event class.

You can access the common key of a group with the `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>.Key` property and you can also iterate over each group with `foreach`.

Hence a nested loop should get you the expected output:

```
foreach (var eventGroup in result.Events.GroupBy(x => x.ShowSystemName))
{
    Console.WriteLine(eventGroup.Key);

    foreach (var eventItem in eventGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{eventItem.EventId} {eventItem.EventTypeId} ...")
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like I don't even need the Select(x =>x) either.  Thanks again!